# Using Set operator in content resolver Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have to update a Content Provider DB. As per requirement, I only can do that using context.getContentResolver().

Bt I am unable to use SET operator in this method.  Can someone help me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean setContentResolver or what ?

Comment: No..user is talking about using joins using content providers

Comment: There is a DB. A column needs to be incremented using SET operator.  I am able to do it using db.rawQuery().  But how do we do it using context.getContentResolver ()

Comment: So,you don't mean to ask about joins through your question?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create new URI and implement it's raw query in a way to incorporate join condition  between the tables.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222294/2819262) SO answer explains in pretty decent way..Have a look!